# Spring Boot Run failed

Tags: spring, spring-boot, build.gradle, h2

I am using Spring to build my application.
I used [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/) to build my project. 
I included the following dependencies:-

1. JPA
2. h2 (database)
3. ThymeLeaf templating engine
4. Spring Actuator
5. DevTools
6. Security

I am using IntelliJ IDEA IDE using Gradle build on Windows Machine.

NOTE:- I have not changed gradle(v4.8) build file.

Down below is the result of running SpringBootApplication:-

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\bin\java.exe" -javaagent:C:\Users\ayman\Downloads\Software\IntelliJIdea\lib\idea_rt.jar=61199:C:\Users\E080978\Downloads\Software\IntelliJIdea\bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Users\E080978\Downloads\Mastercard Image\demo\out\production\classes;C:\Users\E080978\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-actuator\2.0.3.RELEASE\d370eeff676d24523ee530f6abc569474d2f9bf9\spring-boot-starter-actuator-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\E080978\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa\2.0.3.RELEASE\56c909f49b5385793942158e143187ecc8c7b54a\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\E080978\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-security\2.0.3.RELEASE\67de3ced1ebc68c7bbd9bc2ced390821fa682c2f\spring-boot-starter-security-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\E080978\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf\2.0.3.RELEASE\7a8cf11f5b7faa244e1979df491811bc0c858743\spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\E080978\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-aop\2.0.3.RELEASE\a78c7bc25fd51b217f078421dc40d13ddc3b9f8f\spring-boot-starter-aop-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\E080978\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-jdbc\2.0.3.RELEASE\4f5f3411692a0f5efb60f7f583bdfcf49199a3d4\spring-boot-starter-jdbc-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\E080978\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter\2.0.3.RELEASE\ffaa050dbd36b0441645598f1a7ddaf67fd5e678\spring-boot-starter-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\E080978\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-devtools\2.0.3.RELEASE\478e12e423b45d182a409f12a28fb9f0cddf84bf\spring-boot-devtools-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\E080978\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure\2.0.3.RELEASE\f3e3392c3e8e2714fc05bbf0f3ee496ad19eedc7\spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\E080978\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.h2database\h2\1.4.197\bb391050048ca8ae3e32451b5a3714ecd3596a46\h2-1.4.197.jar;C:\Users\E080978\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.micrometer\micrometer-core\1.0.5\c5eaa23f5bb1f0f4b7eb44824093874d0d9165f5\micrometer-core-1.0.5.jar;C:\Users\E080978\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.hibernate\hibernate-core\5.2.17.Final\f2dc36470e7a2ffcf6106bb1625ecf5b54bb5f65\hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar;C:\Users\E080978\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\javax.transaction\javax.transaction-api\1.2\d81aff979d603edd90dcd8db2abc1f4ce6479e3e\javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar;C:\Users\E080978\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.data\spring-data-jpa\2.0.8.RELEASE\8b874afd15da2b4d2d9b8431ad2be0c6829e41fe\spring-data-jpa-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\E080978\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-aspects\5.0.7.RELEASE\afd3f7ecb9d7c2cb3160563f9f64b72223bb0265\spring-aspects-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\E080978\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.security\spring-security-config\5.0.6.RELEASE\60367d94d253c82781b7f9abf2294cd0295e1c1\spring-security-config-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\E080978\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.security\spring-security-web\5.0.6.RELEASE\f502d929ee62f5dce0fc942f5a22faa52eaaac34\spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\E080978\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.0.3.RELEASE\11bc4cc96b08fabad2b3186755818fa0b32d83f\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\E080978\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-actuator\2.0.3.RELEASE\5aa239d8ad6d8130b055caebf44467b9c55d422b\spring-boot-actuator-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\E080978\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot\2.0.3.RELEASE\b874870d915adbc3dd932e19077d3d45c8e54aa0\spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\E080978\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.security\spring-security-core\5.0.6.RELEASE\11c0291cc9cda839b7feb52c519f4a35dc6e251b\spring-security-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\E080978\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-context\5.0.7.RELEASE\243a23f8968de8754d8199d669780d683ab177bd\spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\E080978\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-aop\5.0.7.RELEASE\fdd0b6aa3c9c7a188c3bfbf6dfd8d40e843be9ef\spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\E080978\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.thymeleaf\thymeleaf-spring5\3.0.9.RELEASE\abf84efd83808a70d982d2790f7f3a7bd3a39cf4\thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\E080978\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.thymeleaf.extras\thymeleaf-extras-java8time\3.0.1.RELEASE\d23760d1e53cd70c489ef40dc94ee6bd2371cceb\thymeleaf-extras-java8time-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\E080978\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\2.0.3.RELEASE\7caad34f01d2688919e15e09a90467963e3d5190\spring-boot-starter-logging-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\E080978\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\javax.annotation\javax.annotation-api\1.3.2\934c04d3cfef185a8008e7bf34331b79730a9d43\javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar;C:\Users\E080978\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-orm\5.0.7.RELEASE\4deed5f4a38d62f9dba7db8e010da8b49e322757\spring-orm-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\E080978\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-jdbc\5.0.7.RELEASE\9c78c6b9a6c603f6589b480e165939cde7bab7f9\spring-jdbc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\E080978\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.data\spring-data-commons\2.0.8.RELEASE\5c19af63b5acb0eab39066684e813d5ecd9d03b7\spring-data-commons-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\E080978\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-tx\5.0.7.RELEASE\4ca59b21c61162adb146ad1b40c30b60d8dc42b8\spring-tx-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\E080978\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-web\5.0.7.RELEASE\2e04c6c2922fbfa06b5948be14a5782db168b6ec\spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\E080978\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-beans\5.0.7.RELEASE\c1196cb3e56da83e3c3a02ef323699f4b05feedc\spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\E080978\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-expression\5.0.7.RELEASE\ca01fb473f53dd0ee3c85663b26d5dc325602057\spring-expression-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\E080978\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-core\5.0.7.RELEASE\54b731178d81e66eca9623df772ff32718208137\spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\E080978\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.yaml\snakeyaml\1.19\2d998d3d674b172a588e54ab619854d073f555b5\snakeyaml-1.19.jar;C:\Users\E080978\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.9.6\ea54f6193d224e5e5732bbd4262327eb465397c2\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.9.6.jar;C:\Users\E080978\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-databind\2.9.6\cfa4f316351a91bfd95cb0644c6a2c95f52db1fc\jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar;C:\Users\E080978\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.hdrhistogram\HdrHistogram\2.1.10\9e1ac84eed220281841b75e72fb9de5a297fbf04\HdrHistogram-2.1.10.jar;C:\Users\E080978\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.latencyutils\LatencyUtils\2.0.3\769c0b82cb2421c8256300e907298a9410a2a3d3\LatencyUtils-2.0.3.jar;C:\Users\E080978\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.8.13\ad94df2a28d658a40dc27bbaff6a1ce5fbf04e9b\aspectjweaver-1.8.13.jar;C:\Users\E080978\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.zaxxer\HikariCP\2.7.9\a83113d2c091d0d0f853dad3217bd7df3beb6ae3\HikariCP-2.7.9.jar;C:\Users\E080978\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.hibernate.common\hibernate-commons-annotations\5.0.1.Final\71e1cff3fcb20d3b3af4f3363c3ddb24d33c6879\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\E080978\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jboss.logging\jboss-logging\3.3.2.Final\3789d00e859632e6c6206adc0c71625559e6e3b0\jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\E080978\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.hibernate.javax.persistence\hibernate-jpa-2.1-api\1.0.2.Final\52afb5762c704a6b586e27742470c08f91877fc1\hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\E080978\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.javassist\javassist\3.22.0-GA\3e83394258ae2089be7219b971ec21a8288528ad\javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar;C:\Users\E080978\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\83cd2cd674a217ade95a4bb83a8a14f351f48bd0\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Users\E080978\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jboss\jandex\2.0.3.Final\bfc4d6257dbff7a33a357f0de116be6ff951d849\jandex-2.0.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\E080978\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml\classmate\1.3.4\3d5f48f10bbe4eb7bd862f10c0583be2e0053c6\classmate-1.3.4.jar;C:\Users\E080978\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\dom4j\dom4j\1.6.1\5d3ccc056b6f056dbf0dddfdf43894b9065a8f94\dom4j-1.6.1.jar;C:\Users\E080978\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.thymeleaf\thymeleaf\3.0.9.RELEASE\64185cca50ac808ad034841c84b4013f955465d2\thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\E080978\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\ch.qos.logback\logback-classic\1.2.3\7c4f3c474fb2c041d8028740440937705ebb473a\logback-classic-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\E080978\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.logging.log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.10.0\f7e631ccf49cfc0aefa4a2a728da7d374c05bd3c\log4j-to-slf4j-2.10.0.jar;C:\Users\E080978\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.25\af5364cd6679bfffb114f0dec8a157aaa283b76\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.25.jar;C:\Users\E080978\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.25\da76ca59f6a57ee3102f8f9bd9cee742973efa8a\slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar;C:\Users\E080978\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-jcl\5.0.7.RELEASE\699016ddf454c2c167d9f84ae5777eccadf54728\spring-jcl-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\E080978\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-annotations\2.9.0\7c10d545325e3a6e72e06381afe469fd40eb701\jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar;C:\Users\E080978\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-core\2.9.6\4e393793c37c77e042ccc7be5a914ae39251b365\jackson-core-2.9.6.jar;C:\Users\E080978\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.attoparser\attoparser\2.0.4.RELEASE\5cf02c4d8303a81f0c80971bb1dcd40d3ba96009\attoparser-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\E080978\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.unbescape\unbescape\1.1.5.RELEASE\46dc644ea9c234317d926ebac5bf5d8f114dc1ba\unbescape-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\E080978\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\ch.qos.logback\logback-core\1.2.3\864344400c3d4d92dfeb0a305dc87d953677c03c\logback-core-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\E080978\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.logging.log4j\log4j-api\2.10.0\fec5797a55b786184a537abd39c3fa1449d752d6\log4j-api-2.10.0.jar" com.mastercard.ayman.imagepackt.ImagePacktApplication
12:37:05.891 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings - Included patterns for restart : []
12:37:05.898 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings - Excluded patterns for restart : [/spring-boot-actuator/target/classes/, /spring-boot-devtools/target/classes/, /spring-boot/target/classes/, /spring-boot-starter-[\w-]+/, /spring-boot-autoconfigure/target/classes/, /spring-boot-starter/target/classes/]
12:37:05.898 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls - Matching URLs for reloading : [file:/C:/Users/E080978/Downloads/Mastercard%20Image/demo/out/production/classes/]

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.3.RELEASE)

2018-06-20 12:37:06.301  INFO 23152 --- [  restartedMain] c.m.a.imagepackt.ImagePacktApplication   : Starting ImagePacktApplication on GH-6C9HNH2 with PID 23152 (started by E080978 in C:\Users\E080978\Downloads\Mastercard Image\demo)
2018-06-20 12:37:06.302  INFO 23152 --- [  restartedMain] c.m.a.imagepackt.ImagePacktApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-06-20 12:37:06.374  INFO 23152 --- [  restartedMain] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@17c49070: startup date [Wed Jun 20 12:37:06 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-06-20 12:37:07.824  INFO 23152 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b97b663c] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-06-20 12:37:08.184  INFO 23152 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2018-06-20 12:37:08.349  INFO 23152 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2018-06-20 12:37:08.409  INFO 23152 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-06-20 12:37:08.431  INFO 23152 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2018-06-20 12:37:08.523  INFO 23152 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.17.Final}
2018-06-20 12:37:08.524  INFO 23152 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2018-06-20 12:37:08.566  INFO 23152 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2018-06-20 12:37:08.713  INFO 23152 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2018-06-20 12:37:09.315  INFO 23152 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.t.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl  : HHH000476: Executing import script 'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@2c5eb52e'
2018-06-20 12:37:09.319  INFO 23152 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-06-20 12:37:10.108  WARN 23152 --- [  restartedMain] ion$DefaultTemplateResolverConfiguration : Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/ (please add some templates or check your Thymeleaf configuration)
2018-06-20 12:37:10.246  INFO 23152 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2018-06-20 12:37:10.284  INFO 23152 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2018-06-20 12:37:10.285  INFO 23152 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'dataSource' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2018-06-20 12:37:10.289  INFO 23152 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located MBean 'dataSource': registering with JMX server as MBean [com.zaxxer.hikari:name=dataSource,type=HikariDataSource]
2018-06-20 12:37:10.302  INFO 23152 --- [  restartedMain] c.m.a.imagepackt.ImagePacktApplication   : Started ImagePacktApplication in 4.384 seconds (JVM running for 5.279)
2018-06-20 12:37:10.308  INFO 23152 --- [      Thread-10] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@17c49070: startup date [Wed Jun 20 12:37:06 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-06-20 12:37:10.312  INFO 23152 --- [      Thread-10] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2018-06-20 12:37:10.313  INFO 23152 --- [      Thread-10] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans
2018-06-20 12:37:10.314  INFO 23152 --- [      Thread-10] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-06-20 12:37:10.315  INFO 23152 --- [      Thread-10] .SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl : HHH000477: Starting delayed drop of schema as part of SessionFactory shut-down'
2018-06-20 12:37:10.320  WARN 23152 --- [      Thread-10] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invocation of destroy method failed on bean with name 'inMemoryDatabaseShutdownExecutor': org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Database is already closed (to disable automatic closing at VM shutdown, add ";DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE" to the db URL) [90121-197]
2018-06-20 12:37:10.321  INFO 23152 --- [      Thread-10] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2018-06-20 12:37:10.323  INFO 23152 --- [      Thread-10] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

According to me these two lines are the problem:

**1.The first line**

```
Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b97b663c] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-06-20 12:37:08.184  INFO 23152 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       :
```

**2.The second line**

```
2018-06-20 12:37:10.320  WARN 23152 --- [      Thread-10] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invocation of destroy method failed on bean with name 'inMemoryDatabaseShutdownExecutor': org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Database is already closed (to disable automatic closing at VM shutdown, add ";DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE" to the db URL) [90121-197]
```

I have not done any configuration on the database. Do I need to change database properties for the same?

Answer (score 9):

This is expected. Your app doesn't have any web dependencies, it's simply starting up, running and closing.

Add 

  `<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>`

If you want an embedded container to run.

I should add you will not see this with < 2.0 and those starters, since boot 2.0 and WebFlux Spring boot starter web is no longer a transitive dependency. You must specify it.

Answer (score 1):

> ... add ";DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE" to the db URL ...

Add to `application.properties` file:

`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE`

Answer (score 0):

probably you need to exclude datasource(if you already have your own datasource configured for application) auto configuration in main class.

@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
        DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class})

Comment: I think the problem might be Tomcat is not configured for the project...other project it seems to work but not this project.

Comment: I just check logs of my project. server started  with below warning even saw the same warning for few more beans. so issue could be something else.
Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b97b663c] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)